# XSLT If Select Contains "Value"

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, biztalk, hl7

I would like to write out 4 questions whether they exist or not.So far my approach has been to select="//NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2/NTE_3_Comment" which retrieves all 3 comments. But I am having trouble with

1. Selecting `NTE_3_Comment` where it contains *"Question 1"*(String Value)
2. Writing out *Question 4* when the question does not exist.
3. I also need to output the correct number for the `SETID`.

Note: The question does not actually have the number in it. I am using the ID to sort the output.

Input XML:

```
<NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
    <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>1</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
    <NTE_2_SourceOfComment></NTE_2_SourceOfComment>
    <NTE_3_Comment>Question 1 ? Answer 1</NTE_3_Comment>
</NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
<NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
    <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>1</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
    <NTE_2_SourceOfComment></NTE_2_SourceOfComment>
    <NTE_3_Comment>Question 2 ? Answer 2</NTE_3_Comment>
</NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
<NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
    <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>1</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
    <NTE_2_SourceOfComment></NTE_2_SourceOfComment>
    <NTE_3_Comment>Question 3? Answer 3</NTE_3_Comment>
</NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
```

Expected Output XML:

```
<NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
    <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>1</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
    <NTE_2_SourceOfComment></NTE_2_SourceOfComment>
    <NTE_3_Comment>Question 1 ? Answer 1</NTE_3_Comment>
</NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
<NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
    <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>2</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
    <NTE_2_SourceOfComment></NTE_2_SourceOfComment>
    <NTE_3_Comment>Question 2 ? Answer 2</NTE_3_Comment>
</NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
<NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
    <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>3</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
    <NTE_2_SourceOfComment></NTE_2_SourceOfComment>
    <NTE_3_Comment>Question 3 ? Answer 3</NTE_3_Comment>
</NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
<NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
    <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>4</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
    <NTE_2_SourceOfComment></NTE_2_SourceOfComment>
    <NTE_3_Comment>Question 4 ? *Blank* </NTE_3_Comment>
</NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
```

I am looking for suggestions that can help me change my approach to this solution. Thanks in Advance.

Solution: Thanks to @O.R.Mapper suggestion. All four questions will be written out every time whether the question exist or not. The answers will display blank if the question does not exist in the source.

```
            <NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
            <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>1</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
            <NTE_3_Comment>Question 1 ?<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2/NTE_3_Comment[starts-with(text(),'Question 1')],'?')"/>
            </NTE_3_Comment>
            </NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>

            <NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
            <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>2</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
            <NTE_3_Comment>Question 2 ?<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2/NTE_3_Comment[starts-with(text(),'Question 2')],'?')"/>
            </NTE_3_Comment>
            </NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>

            <NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
            <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>3</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
            <NTE_3_Comment>Question 3 ?<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2/NTE_3_Comment[starts-with(text(),'Question 3')],'?')"/>
            </NTE_3_Comment>
            </NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>

            <NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
            <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>4</NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
            <NTE_3_Comment>Question 4 ? <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2/NTE_3_Comment[starts-with(text(),'Question 4')],'?')"/>
            </NTE_3_Comment>
            </NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Selecting NTE_3_Comment where it contains Question 1" ?

Comment: I am looking for a specific string. In this example I would be looking for "Question 1".

Comment: Since this is related to a Biztalk map it might help if you add the source and target schema (parts). Has the source `NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments` indeed always the value `1`?

Comment: In my environment the source `NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments` always has the value of `1`

Comment: Is it correct to assume that you will always output 4 `NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2` result nodes? Is it possible that the source message will have only 2 nodes and you need to output "Question 3 ? \*Blank\*" (like for Question 4)?

Comment: @Filburt that is correct. There is a possibility that only 2 nodes exist in the source and questions 3 and 4 will output as blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for (1) would be the following XPath expression:

```
//NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2/NTE_3_Comment[starts-with(text(), 'Question 1')]
```

Comment: I think the OP is rather looking for a way to split the element text into the question part before the "?" and the answer part (after the "?") than hardcoding the text into his xpath.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, Your suggestion pointed me in the right direction. `substring-after(//NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2/NTE_3_Comment[starts-with(text(),'Question 1)],'?')`   I will supply a complete answer when I have completed the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A complete xslt solution could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <root>
            <xsl:call-template name="for.loop">
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="4" />
                <xsl:with-param name="answer" select="substring-after(//NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2[position() = 1]/NTE_3_Comment, '?')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="for.loop">

        <xsl:param name="i" />
        <xsl:param name="count" />
        <xsl:param name="answer" />

        <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
            <NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
                <NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$i" />
                </NTE_1_SetIdNotesAndComments>
                <NTE_2_SourceOfComment></NTE_2_SourceOfComment>
                <NTE_3_Comment>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$answer = ''">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Question ', $i, ' ? *Blank*')" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Question ', $i, ' ? ', $comment)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
               </NTE_3_Comment>
            </NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2>
        </xsl:if>

        <!-- Repeat the loop until finished -->
        <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">
            <xsl:call-template name="for.loop">
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count">
                <xsl:with-param name="comment" select="substring-after(//NTE_NotesAndCommentsSegment_2[position() = $i + 1]/NTE_3_Comment, '?')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Filburt, This solution only outputs the Answer. Its important that I know what question doesnt exist in order to include it in the output.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the sequence in the output. I'm little confused that your xpath `starts-with(text(), 'Question X')` works since you said your actual data doesn't contain the sequence number.

Comment: Correct, I wanted to stay true to this example and answer it properly. Filburt it does not contain the sequence number but I know what the 4 questions will be. `Purpose for Exam ? Annual Physical` starts with Purpose substring ? gives me `Annual Physical`. Also the question may not come in the correct order. I have to output them in the correct order. Thanks for your time Filburt

Comment: In this case my answer doesn't fit because it relies on the order of the source elements. Good you found your working solution - happy biztalking ;-)